# Wget mirroring accept list

Tags: file, wget

If I do not add anything to the accept list for mirroring; will wget default to all file types?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything is downloaded. You can skip certain files using `--reject` option. Example:

```
--reject swf, mpeg
```

skips swf nd mpeg files.